# How can I know if I should access value by index or key in an OrderedDictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, indexing, key-value, ordereddictionary

All this time I was using Dictionary to store key/value pairs until I came across this new class called OrderedDictionary which has got an additional feature of accessing data through index.

So, I wanted to know when could/would I be running into any situation that would ask me to access value through index when I have the key already. I have a small snippet below.

```
        OrderedDictionary od = new OrderedDictionary();

        od.Add("Key1", "Val1");
        od.Add("Key2", "Val2");
        od.Add("Key3", "Val3");
        od.Add("Key4", "Val4");
```

Probably, the code above may not seem appropriate but, I would really appreciate if someone can give a better one to answer by question.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Well first you need to ask in what situation would you need to use an `OrderedDictionary`

Comment: The difference between _Dictionary_ and _OrderedDictionary_ is that Dictionary is type safe while OrderedDictionary uses any object generally. It stores it as _object_ and you must cast it when getting a value. If you are storing data with the same type use Dictionary.

Comment: I can imagine it could be useful if you use `foreach` loop. For example you want the new key-value pair to be the first in the loop, you can use `od.Insert(0, "newKey", "newValue")`

Comment: I've seen it used 1) in place of a counter in a 'foreach' loop, 2) in a kind of 'getNext' function and 3) in one odd case where the key was a string and each key was a sequential number read from xml but not cast as an integer and the index and key exactly matched. In all cases, the coding seemed unnecessary and trivial solutions would have been available for what might have been more appropriate data storage objects, so I second @Rhumbori's point.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ That's _one_ difference between the framework _implementations_.  The main difference is the fact that `OrderedDictionary` is, well,  ordered (by key), while the `Dictionary` is not.  There are plenty of generic implementations of `OrderedDictionary` out there - Microsoft just has not had a compelling reason to spend the time and resources on putting one in the framework.

Comment: Well your sample code does not access the items by index (or by key for that matter) so it's impossible to determine which would be more appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to know when could/would I be running into any situation that would ask me to access value through index when I have the key already

I follow the YAGNI principle - You Aren't Gonna Need It.  If you already know the key, then what value is there in accessing by index?  The point of a dictionary is to do FAST lookups by key (by not scanning the entire collection).  With an `OrderedDictionary`, lookups are still fast, but inserts and updates are marginally slower because the structure must keep the keys and indices in sync. Plus, the current framework implementation is not generic, so you'll have to do more casting, but there are plenty of 3rd party generic implementations out there. The fact that MS did not create a generic implementation may tell you something about the value of that type overall.

So the situation you "could" run into is needing to access the values in key order.  In that case you'll need to decide if you do that often enough to warrant the overhead of an `OrderedDictionary` or if you can just use Linq queries to order the items outside of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

#### Theory of Hash based collections

Before choosing between Dictionary and OrderedDictionary, let's look how some collections are built.

**Arrays**
Arrays provide time constant access when you now the index of your value. 
So keys must be integers. If you don't know the index, you must traverse the full collection to check your value is the one you're looking for.

**Dictionaries**
Purpose of dictionary is to provide a (relatively) time constant access to any value in it when key is not an integer. However, since there is not always a perfect hash function to get an integer from a value, there will collisions of hash codes and then when several values have the same hash codes, they are added in a array. And search for theses collided values will be slower (since it must traverse the array).

**OrderedDictionary**
OrderedDictionary is kind of mix between the two previous collections. Index search will/should be the fastest (however you need to profile to be sure of that point). The problem with index search is that apart from special cases, you don't know the index in which your value was stored, so you must rely on the key. Which makes me wonder, why would you need an OrderedDictionary ?

As one comment implies, I would be very interested to know what's your use case for such a collection. Most of the times, you either know the index or don't know it, because it relies on the value nature. So you should either use an array or a Dictionary, not a mix of both.

**Two use cases very different:**

```
        KeyValuePair<string, string>[] values = new KeyValuePair<string, string>[4];
        values[0] = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Key1", "Value1");
        // And so on...
        // Or
        Dictionary<string, Person> persons = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
        var asker = new Person { FirstName = "pradeep", LastName=" pradyumna" }; 
        persons.Add(asker.Key, asker);
        // Later in the code, you cannot know the index of the person without having the person instance.
```